# How to use Google Cloud Text-to-Speech on Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

I want to use Google Cloud Text-to-Speech on my Android app.
I found a sample code but I don't know how to use it in my app.

I run this sample and it worked.
https://github.com/changemyminds/Google-Cloud-TTS-Android

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a lot late response but still, if you had that issue then I had the solution of it and could say this would definitely help those who are facing the same issues, so if you are not having a heavy app size or it doesn't your Gradle conflicts with maven then you may prefer:- https://github.com/changemyminds/Google-Cloud-TTS-Android but if this link causes you errors as I got do prefer:-
https://github.com/ivso0001/GoogleCloudTextToSpeech this one is the very simpler so you won't be facing big issues. as it does help me too.

Answer (score -1):

How to use it totally depends on your needs. You can use some patterns from this example. Also, you can read [official Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/) and use Java examples, but most important is [TTS android reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) with Java and Kotlin.

You can try to find in Google something like "Android TTS tutorials" to get more understanding about the theme.